# Jinja2 return error when dict is empty - despite conditional in front

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2

I have an ansible play where I create a file from Jinja2 template.
In that file I have following body:

```
{% if app_instances is defined and (app_instances | length) > 0 %}
  {% for i, i_opts in app_instances.items() %}
  server{{ loop.index0 }} {
    some_port = {{ i_opts.some_port | default(default_some_port + (2*loop.index0)) }}
    other_port = {{ i_opts.other_port | default(default_other_port + (2*loop.index0)) }}
  }
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
  server0 {
    some_port = {{ default_some_port }}
    other_port = {{ default_other_port }}
  }
{% endif %}
```

The dictionary I parse is looking like this (sometimes dictionary does not exists is there is no data available - then file should have default values)

```
app_instances:
  instance0:
    hostname: someHost
    some_port: 10050
    other_port: 10051
```

Now when I run the play and parse the dictionary it fills the file quite nicely, however when I have an empty dict the play return error on line with  `items()`

error - message ---------

```
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'app_instances'
```

How to create a valid conditional to ignore items method if condition is not valid and dict is parsed empty so that file can be created with content in else section. What did I miss here?
Why for loo is still trying to strip dict var even if conditional is not valid when dict is empty?

Comment: Just a comment when I tried also do this with empty dict {} it return me the error: ` "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'loop' is undefined"`

Comment: Do a `debug` of `app_instances` most likely it won't be that empty. Also if you want a anyone to be able to help in here you should put the whole error'ing step not just the message.

Comment: Do not comment on your question. Update it!

Comment: Also note that you should actually use the `for ... else ...` statement of Jinja for this